# Simulating Brownian motion in R. Is this correct?

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I have a Weiner process $\{W(t)\}_{t\ge0}$ with $\sigma^2=\text{Var}(W(1))=1$. For a real constant $\epsilon>0$ consider the differential ratio process $\Delta_\epsilon=\{\Delta_\epsilon(t)\}_{r>0}$ given by
\begin{equation}
\Delta_\epsilon(t) = \frac{W(t+\epsilon)-W(t)}{\epsilon}, \quad \text{for} \ t>0.
\end{equation}

I want to simulate a sample path of $\{\Delta_\epsilon(t)\}_{t\in(0,1]}$ for small $\epsilon>0$ in Rstudio.

Simulating a basic Weinerprocess/Brownian motion is easy in R, one can do it by the function `rweiner()` or by plotting the cumulative sum of standard normally distributed variables. The part that confuses me is how to simulate the $W(t+\epsilon)$. What I've done is used [rwiener()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/e1071/versions/1.7-3/topics/rwiener) and simply passed the `end` parameter to $1+\epsilon$.

```
epsilon = 10e-1
weinerEps = rwiener(end = 1+epsilon, frequency = 1000)
weiner = rwiener(end = 1, frequency = 1000)

Delta = (wienerEps - wiener)/epsilon

plot(Delta , type="l")
```

I'm not sure this is correct though.

Comment: You have some typos in your formulas.

Comment: Be consistent in the spelling of "Wiener".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you have a difference of $W(t+\epsilon)$ and $W(t)$, don't you want the same realization of $W$ before you take the difference?

I think you should run $\texttt{rwiener}()$ once, store the result, and then pull out both $W(t+\epsilon)$ and $W(t)$, subtract and then divide by $\epsilon$.

```
library('e1071')
epsilon = 1e-1  # 1/10=1e-1 and not 10e-1=1.
freq    = 1000
wiener  = rwiener(end = 1+epsilon, frequency = freq)
w       = wiener[1:1000];
w_eps   = wiener[(1+freq*epsilon):(1000+freq*epsilon)];
Delta   = (w_eps - w)/epsilon
plot(Delta , type="l")
```

[image]

Comment: If I run Wiener once, don't I already have $W(t)$ since that's what $\texttt{rwiener()}$ simulates? How do I extract $W(t+\epsilon)$ from this?

Comment: Run $\texttt{rwiener()}$ from time $0$ to time $t+\epsilon$.  Then you can take $W(t)$  from time $0$ to $t$ and $W(t+\epsilon)$ from $\epsilon$ to $t+\epsilon$.